# They used to think we are/were siblings?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, tense-agreement

I happened to see this sentence the other day:

> They used to think we *are* siblings.

Is this correct usage? I have a feeling that it is wrong. But If it is correct, Is there a meaning difference if I turn *are* to *were* (which I think is the right usage) in this construction:

> They used to think we *were* siblings.

Here is an other example:

> I used to think I *am* the fittest.

> I used to think I *was* the fittest.

Are there any situations in which the present form of the auxiliary verb is used after we use "used to"?

Comment: Obviously if you had been siblings then it would still be true now, but _were_ is more usual in this kind of sentence.

Comment: It's an issue of tense, with 'am the fittest' meaning that in the past, you used to think that you are the fittest now, which makes very little sense. The other sentence implies that you used to think that you were [back then] the fittest, which would make more sense because the tenses would agree.

Comment: @KateBunting Yeah, siblings are always siblings. So, are they both right in this case or is the usage of _were_ (even though it's usual to use it) wrong?

Comment: @JoeKerr What about the first case? Does _are_ make more sense or should one go with _were_ in that case as well? The relationship ("are siblings") there seems to be persisting to the future (not just the past).

Comment: @Tangent I think that 'were' would be correct in the first case because a general rule of writing that I follow is that the tenses have to match, so the first one would be used (which is past tense) and were (which is also past tense), and for the second one, there would have to be past tense as well.

Comment: I meant to suggest that _were_ is both usual and acceptable, even though it might seem illogical. In your second example, _were_ seems appropriate because you may not be as fit now as you were in the past!